# TotalPrice of the cart is displaying NaN

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-context

So I am dealing with rather a complex problem at least for me. Here I have basic cart functionality(add, remove, etc...). The problems I am facing are this. So I am able to add an item to the cart, but when I try to add the different item to the cart it is not doing it. When I try to add the same item that I added before, it is changing the number of cart items, so that is kind of working. I have a problem with a total in the Checkout Component, it is displaying NaN instead of total Price. I know it's is a quite bit of code, and I would be really grateful if someone could point me to my mistakes. Thanks

Context Api

```
import React from "react";

function getCartFromLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("cart")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    : [];
}

const CartContext = React.createContext({});

function CartProvider({ children }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState(getCartFromLocalStorage());
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = React.useState(0);

  function onUpdate() {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
   
    // total
    let newTotal = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
      return (total += cartItem.amount * cartItem.RegularPrice);
    }, 0);
    newTotal = parseFloat(newTotal.toFixed(3));
    setTotal(newTotal);
    
    // cartItems
    let newCartItems = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
      return (total += cartItem.amount);
    }, 0);
    setCartItems(newCartItems);
  }
  React.useEffect(onUpdate, [cart]);
  
  // remove
  const removeItem = (key) => {
    setCart([...cart].filter((item) => item.key !== key));
  };
  
  // addToCart
  const addToCart = (book) => {
    const { key, image, bookName, by, RegularPrice } = book;
    let item = cart.find((item) => item.key === key);
    if (item) {
      item.amount++;
      onUpdate();
    } else {
      setCart(
        cart.concat({
          amount: 1,
          price: book.RegularPrice,
          
          ...book
        })
      );
    }
  };
  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cart,
        cartItems,
        total,
        removeItem,
        addToCart,
        clearCart
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { CartContext, CartProvider };
```

CartLink

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {FiShoppingCart} from 'react-icons/fi'
import { CartContext } from "../../context/cart";
export default function CartLink() {

  const { cartItems} = React.useContext(CartContext);
  return (
    <div className="cartlink__container">
      <Link to="/cart">
      <FiShoppingCart />
      </Link>
      <span className="cartlink__total">{cartItems}</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Cart Item

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { CartContext } from "../../context/cart";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
export default function CartItem({ key, image,bookName, RegularPrice, by, amount }) {
  const {removeItem} = useContext(CartContext)
  return (
      <div  key={key} className="cart__item">
          <img className='cart__image' src={image}  />
        <div className='cart__itemdesc'>
         <h4>{bookName}</h4>
        <h6 className='cart__by'>By: {by}</h6>
        <button
          className="cart__removebtn"
          onClick={() => {
            removeItem(key);
          }}
         >
          Remove
        </button>
        </div>  
        <span className='circle'><span className='circleone'></span></span>
        <span>{RegularPrice}</span>
        <div>
          <Checkout />
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Checkout

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import { CartContext } from '../../context/cart'
import {Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import EmptyCart from './EmptyCart';

const Checkout = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const {cart, total} = useContext(CartContext)
  if (cart.length === 0) {
    return <EmptyCart />;
  }

    return (
        <div>
            <Link to='/stripecontainer' className='checkout__btnOne'>Proceed to 
         Checkout</Link>    
            <h2>total : ${total}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Checkout
```

```
import React,{useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react'
import './Home.css'
import Books from './Books'
import { BookContext } from "../../context/books";
const Home = () => {
   const {data, handleSelectCategory, currentSelectedCategory } =useContext(BookContext)
    return (
        <div className='books__container' >
          <h1 className='categories'>Categories</h1>
            {Object.keys(data).map((key, index)=>{
            let books = data[key];
            return (
              <> 
              <span key={key} onClick={() => handleSelectCategory(key)} className='books__list' >
              {books[0].category}
              </span>         
             </>
              );})}
              <Books category={currentSelectedCategory} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: `let newCartItems = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => { return (total += cartItem.amount); }, 0); setCartItems(newCartItems);` That calls `setCartItems` with a single number, which could be what you want, but sounds odd to the ear. I would expect `setCartItems` to take an array of CartItem objects...

Comment: Under cart item: `<button className="cart__removebtn" onClick={() => { removeItem(key); }}>` seems fishy... usually html event listeners are wrapped in `"`... So if that isn't causing a unrelated problem, I guess I learned something new today.

Comment: @ShanerM13 I think you have learned something new.

Comment: @ Heretic Monkey It's still the same

Comment: @mura1, sweeeeeeet.

Comment: @ShanerM13 but thanks for the help

Comment: is the output for book what you are expecting?

Comment: Honestly, its probably against SO policy to do this, but a codesandbox.io environment might be very nice... with some expected input to pass to it.

Comment: ok I'll create it

Comment: maybe I found the problem, In the console am I getting the ```Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.``` I added one component in the question. where I think the problem is located

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sound-5y7pg?file=/src/BookContext.js

Comment: @ShanerM13 It's totally fine to ask for and to post a CodeSandbox.  What's not ok is when askers just link to a CodeSandbox and don't *also* include relevant code in the body of their question.

Comment: It did not save the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems in the computation of `newTotal`.

1. The `price` for the each of the items in the `cart` is a `string` like `"$17.47"`.  Doing math operations on that `string` returns `NaN`.  You should really store a `number` here.  As a workaround you can use `parseFloat`, but you need to remove the `$` first because `parseFloat("$17.47")` is `NaN`.
2. You are simultaneously assigning and returning.  You just want to `return` the new value.  So don't use `+=`.

```
const newTotal = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
  return total + cartItem.amount * parseFloat(cartItem.price.replace('$', ''));
}, 0);
setTotal(newTotal);
```

---

Regarding the non-unique keys: you are using a property `book.key` which does not seem to exist [in your data set](https://json-api-smaiil.herokuapp.com/books).  This also makes it impossible to remove an item from the cart or to have multiple different items in the cart since you are matching based on this non-existent `key`.  The books *do* have a unique property `id` which you should use instead, both as the `key` property in your JSX and for filtering the array.

---

The `item.amount++;` in `addToCart` is a mutation of state.  You need to replace the `item` with a copied object.

```
setCart(
  cart.map((item) =>
    item.id === book.id ? { ...item, amount: item.amount + 1 } : item
  )
);
```

---

`total` and `cartItems` can be derived from the state of `cart`, so they don't really need to be their own state.

---

Thanks for including a CodeSandbox.  It it so much easier to find your problem when I can run your code.

Comment: it is giving me the error of ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-hooks-5ebcg?file=/src/CartContext.js

Comment: `CartProvider` is inside of `BookProvider` so If you want to you could just store a keyed object of ids and quantities, like `{"3": 1, "5": 2}`, and all the other info you could get by looking up the book by id.

Comment: The thing that has changed is that now I can add different items, but for some weird reason when I press remove one it clears them all

Comment: It is not doing that for me.

Comment: I hate sandbox, it has kicked me out, cant even look at the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230522/discussion-between-linda-paiste-and-mura1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with JSon, but if you're getting NaN at the end then try a simple test of printing all the values to the screen to trace where the issue begins (where an unexpected value pops up).

As for the cart item, you say you can only add the same item to the list, then try printing the second item right before adding it to the cart. It could be a reference problem perhaps.

Comment: I can add one(image, by, bookName) but the number of cart items is changing

Answer (score 0):

I think the `NaN` is coming because the `RegularPrice` property is moved to `price` in `addToCart` but then `RegularPrice` is used in the reducing function in `onUpdate`.

Comment: it's still the same